# Issue calling a stored procedure on ef5 using SqlQuery

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a stored procedure that searches my person table, I want to use it on my ef5 project and I want to call it using a SQL statement like this:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT [dbo].[sp_Search_Natural_Person] ({0}, {1}, {2})";
System.Object[] parameters = { buscar, buscarTipo, buscarPor};
var resultado = db_hms.Database.SqlQuery<PagingPersonItem>(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();
```

I need to call it this way because my database schema is changing a lot, and the option update model from DB has never work fine, so I delete end recreate the model.

The `PagingPersonItem` is a class that contains the properties of the query's result.

But I'm getting this error:

spanish:

> No se encuentra la columna "dbo" o la función definida por el usuario o agregado "dbo.sp_Search_Natural_Person"; o bien, el nombre es ambiguo

and English will be something like:

> Cannot find the column named "DBO" or the function defined by the user added "dbo.sp_Search_Natural_person"; or the name ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your SP_Search_Natural_Person really a StoredProcedure or it's a user defined function?

From your select statement it looks like a Udf, but from the name it looks like a stored procedure.

For stored procedure, I would use this statement:

```
string sqlQuery = "EXEC [dbo].[sp_Search_Natural_Person] {0}, {1}, {2}";
System.Object[] parameters = { buscar, buscarTipo, buscarPor};
var resultado = db_hms.Database.SqlQuery<PagingPersonItem>(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();
```

Comment: the first time i try this i leave the () on the parameters and it was making it fail now is working great tks!